# Plot lines on an Excel chart

Tags: excel

I need to plot a line between two points on an excel spreadsheet. In my ideal world, it'd become a thin box with colors and text, but at this stage, I'll take what I can get.

Data:

```
min max value
1   2   28
2   3   64
3   5   87
4   7   99
```

In the end, there would be lines from {1,28} to {2,28}, {2,64} to {3,64}, {3,87} to {5,87} and {4,99} to {7,99}.

Flipping the axes in Excel, apparently, doesn't leave the original axes intact - it goes to numbering the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you rearrange the data as shown in the animated gif below and then make separate plots for each min/max pair, you get the lines drawn just as you described.  I show adding just the last min/max pair, and added labels for the sake of a legend. This seems to do what you described, but if not let me know.
[image]